# Text to Date function in Excel

Tags: excel

In Excel I have a row with many dates in it:
Oct-13  Nov-13  Dec-13  Jan-14  Feb-14  Mar-14  Apr-14  May-14

However they are coded as: 
`=TEXT(AD42,"MMM-YY")` `=TEXT(AD41,"MMM-YY")` `=TEXT(AD40,"MMM-YY")` `=TEXT(AD33,"MMM-YY")` `=TEXT(AD31,"MMM-YY")` `=TEXT(AD28,"MMM-YY")` `=TEXT(AD26,"MMM-YY")` `=TEXT(AD23,"MMM-YY")`, respectively.

I need to increase all of their numbers by one. So Oct-13 is now Oct-14. They are all formatted as general. I have tried to change the numbers multiple times but the majority of times it gets coded as Jan-00. This was a file given to me that I did not create, but simply trying to manipulate. I don't really think Excel has the greatest continuity with the Date function.

In the end I simply took the long way and just did: 'MMM-YY
Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add 365 to the cell containing the date (for example):

```
=TEXT(AD42+365,"MMM-YY")
```

Or if you would like to instead accommodate for leapyears, just pull out the year number and add 1 to it:

```
=LEFT(AD42,4)&(RIGHT(AD42,2)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add 1 to the year of the date:

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AD42)+1,MONTH(AD42),DAY(AD42)),"MMM-YY")
```

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the leap year issue, I'd go with this solution instead of just adding 365 days:

```
=LEFT(TEXT(AD42,"MMM-YY"),4)&INT(RIGHT(TEXT(AD42,"MMM-YY"),2))+1
```